# Android app crashed after scrolling the list

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a problem. Sorry for bad english.

My android app crashed after scrolling the list and pushed any button.
In stack trace:

```
   The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.
   Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. 
   Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.
```

Content of the adapter wasn't changed. The error occurs when scrolling and clicking another button during it. After clicking button used the same listView, but with a different content.

Here is my code:
CustomAdapter.getView

```
private ArrayList<ListData> eventsRecommended;
private ArrayList<ListData> eventsAll;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if ( rowView == null )
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inetlist, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.eventTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.eventDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.eventImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.eventTickets = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buyTicketButton);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    ListData p = getItem(position);
    holder.eventTitle.setText(p.title);
    holder.eventDescription.setText(p.description);
    if ( p.ticketLink == null || p.ticketLink.length() < 1 )
        holder.eventTickets.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        holder.eventTickets.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.eventTickets.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    holder.eventImage.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(p.pic));

    return rowView;
}
```

Button's clicking change boolean value of flag

```
public ListData getItem(int position)
{
    try
    {
        if (flag == Boolean.FALSE)
            return eventsRecommended.get(position);
        else
            return eventsAll.get(position);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use other custom listview adapter after clicking a button. 
Does it crash with it?
Possibly problem in it?

Comment: Yes, it works! But how to explain application crash?